# Socket handle leak happening on Azure Web App

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I have been stuck in one issue. I am getting error of "Unable to connect to the remote server. An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions".

After searching on web and taking help of azure support, I came to know that if Web App reaches outbound connection limit of azure web app instance, it refuses connections or kill extra connections. Here is the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgfOM.png) of open socket handles

My application calls third party WebAPI and wcf service. I have written code to close connections after making call to APIs. but it doesn't work for me. I did following code to call Web API.

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("www.xyz.com");
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.KeepAlive = false;
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Handshake");
byte[] bodyData;
bodyData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input_data);
request.ContentLength = bodyData.Length;
request.GetRequestStream().Write(bodyData, 0, bodyData.Length);
request.GetRequestStream().Flush();
request.GetRequestStream().Close();

using (var response = request.GetResponse())
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), 
Encoding.UTF8))
{
   string output_data = reader.ReadToEnd();
 }   

  response.Close();   
 }
```

Could anyone guide me how to get rid on this issue?

Comment: If scale up  your service plan to standard tier is possible, I recommand that you could use that plan. According to Azure subscription and service limits  we could know that Web Sockets per instance is  Unlimited if the service plan is standard+.

Comment: Have you found out your what your issue was? We are currently looking for a same kind of issue where we seem to hit an instance limit (TCP connection, socket, etc.) because when we scale-out more instances, api performance is increased even if all instances CPU and RAM is very low...